# Set multiple values to an element

Tags: jquery, prettyphoto, rel

I'm making a DIV clickable like so:

```
jQuery(".post").click(function(){
    window.location=jQuery(this).find(".post-title a").attr("href");
    return false;
});
```

but I also want to add rel attribute to it so the link can open in a lightbox. I tried adding `.attr("rel=prettyphoto")` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Have you looked at the [API](http://api.jquery.com/)? All you need to do is add the method-name to the end of the `http://api.jquery.com/` URL: to give, in this case [`http://api.jquery.com/attr/`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the `rel` attribute on page load, not on click, and make sure you do that before you init the lightbox script. There is not point in setting the attribute on click, as the page reload would take place anyway, and the attribute would be gone.

So:

```
// Inside this block we're sure the DOM is loaded,
// so we can init our stuff
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Add rel to post title links
    $('.post .post-title a').attr('rel', 'lightbox');

    // Now init your lightbox script
    // (your init code here)

    // Now set the click handler (does not have to be last)
    $(".post").click(function(){
        window.location=$(this).find(".post-title a").attr("href");
        return false;
    });

});
```

Comment: now if you could just guide me how to set it on load for each? :p

Comment: .post-title a already has a rel attrib, I'm making the DIV clickable which doesn't

Comment: Well, if you're using [this lightbox plugin](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/), that wouldn't work (it only works on anchors). I'm not sure what you're trying to do. What do you want to happen when the div is clicled? Page reload, or to open the lightbox?

Comment: clicking on post-title already opens the lightbox, but I want to make the whole div (.post) clickable.

Comment: So you'll have to fire the lightbox manually, not use `window.location`.

Comment: Ah ok, will use $.prettyPhoto(open) then

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
$("whatever").attr("rel", "prettyphoto");
```

As the docs [note](http://api.jquery.com/attr/):

```
attr( name ) is the getter
attr( name, value ) is the setter
```

Answer (score 0):

if I were you, i'd break it out into steps, you'd actually answer your own question in the process.

```
jQuery(".post").click(function(){

    // store the link in var
    var link = jQuery(this).find(".post-title a");

    // set the rel
    link.attr('rel','prettyphoto');

    // get the href
    var location = link.attr("href");

    window.location=location;
    return false;
});
```

Also, do remember that the `.attr( attrName [, attrVal] )` method has two arguments: if you write the second argument in your function, it will *set* a value.